# Drill Down Issue in Reports after click on Bar Chart Salesforce

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforcedx, report-chart

Running into a problem with standard Salesforce reports, drill down. The filters work well when the bar charts along with tabular data is shown, but as soon as one clicks on a bar chart to drill down further, the previously set filters are lost. This leads to showing wrong and irrelevant data in the report.

Report type is custom  where report type category is "Accounts and Contacts". Data is filtered based on create date in Previous FY and cross filters 
 are applied on Accounts with opportunities  as stage equals "Closed Won" and Month Earned(Custom Fields) is greater or equal to specific date.

The same functionality is working well in the Salesforce classic.

In Attached Screenshot validate and master validate field are true but it showing Wrong Values here, once I click the single bar column in the chart.

[image]